# How to determine xsetwacom default settings for connected devices

Tags: linux, bash-scripting

Since xsetwacom will only apply settings temporarily, I would like to write a startup script that applies preferences for my Tablet. I'm wondering if there is a way to determine all possible settings that are available for the tablet I'm using?

Answer (score 0):

`xsetwacom -s get "[your device]" all` will list all the current parameters for your device, as they would be set in a shell or script (As described [here](https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/wiki/xsetwacom#interaction-with-gnome-settings-daemon)).

`xsetwacom --list` will list connected Wacom devices.